# Without using if statement, how to generate a username in java

Tags: java, substring

Okay, my class assignment is to write a code to generate a username.  But, it can be no more than 7 letters of the last name.  if there are fewer than 7 letters in the last name, then all the letters would be used.  But the prof says no if statements.  Any ideas ? The one I wrote works fine for names 7 or more letters but sends an error for short last names.  Here it is:

```
    //find first initial of firstName
    char firstInitial = firstName.charAt(0);

    //limit last name in userName to 7 characters
    String shortLastName = lastName.substring(0, 7);

    //create a username using the first letter of firstName and lastName (but no more than 7 letters)
    String userName = (firstInitial + shortLastName);

    //print username in lowercase
    System.out.println((firstName + " " + lastName + "'s standard username is:" + userName).toLowerCase())
```

Really just need an idea about how to proceed.  Possibly an example to look at. I've given up....

Comment: Does the ternary operator count as an if statement?

Comment: Professor said only string and math class.

Comment: Then that is OK, as it is Java syntax...

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Math` class `min` function to decide if you should use the full last name or just the first 7 characters:

```
String username = firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, Math.min(7, lastName.length()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ternary operator (which is nothing but a `if` statement basically):

```
String shortened = name.length() > 7 ? name.substring(0, 7) : name;
```

[edit] To your edit "only string and math"; you could also use `Math.min` with maximum/actual string length.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [java.lang.Math#min(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29)

```
//limit last name in userName to 7 characters
String shortLastName = lastName.substring(0, Math.min(7, lastName.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the error it throws.

```
String shortLastName;
try
{
   shortLastName = lastName.substring(0, 7);
}
   catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) // If this is the error, I'm not positive on that
{
   shortLastName = lastName;
}
```

But using Min is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If at all you do not want to use any comparison this is the way

```
    try {
        System.out.println(firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, 7));
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println(firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, lastName.length()));
    }
```